# Am I calculating the fuel consumption correctly?

Tags: piston-engine, fuel-consumption

I'm trying to calculate the fuel consumption for l550e engine. In its [datasheet](https://limflug.de/en/support/downloads.php?type=datasheets&id=L550-E-datasheet-en.pdf&action=download) you can see this graph:

[image]

At 6500 RPM, engine power is around 48hp and the SFC is 345g/HPh. Ok, then the fuel consumption rate is:

fuel consumption rate: 345g/HPh * 48HP = 16560g/h

Am I right? We can assume the density of gasoline is 0.755g/ml based on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasoline#Density). Thus this engine at this RPM consumes 22Lit/h. right? Isn't it too much high?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your math is right.

For comparison, the [Rotax 582](https://web.archive.org/web/20170722033156/http://docusearch.flyrotax.com/files/pdf/d04495.pdf) which is also a two-stroke engine, outputs 48 kW (take-off performance) and uses 26.5 L/h. The stated specific fuel consumption is 425 g/kWh (317 g/HPh), which is close enough to the Limbach number.

Small two-stroke gasoline engines are generally less efficient than four-stroke ones.

Comment: Yes 2 strokes have an SFC roughly 25% higher than 4 strokes, more or less comparable to turboprops.